# Why would you integrate Rails with Angularjs and not keep them seperate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Why would you want to integrate rails and angularjs in the same "project" and not keep them 100% separate?

What are the potential downsides of keeping both the backend (rails) and Angularjs app in separate projects?

Answer (score 1):

Note: Anecdotal response.

Over the last 9 months I have worked on a larger angularjs (1.4) and rails app (4.2) in a single code base and we are starting a new version that is completely separate front and back end.

Keeping together there is a lot of coupling in the code, it is better than just straight rails views in some respects but it most angular controllers are tied directly to an endpoint on the API, which is tied directly to a single service object to deal with the data manipulation.  Another down side is independant deployability, in order to change an image somewhere the entire app has to be redeployed.  Also, the skill level to get someone on the project is quite high, they have to know some pretty advanced rails stuff and also angular.
One benefit of this is that it is easier to do transactions and ensure data integrity.  Another benefit is that once someone knows the system, it is easier for them to grasp changes to it.  But that ramp up time is quite high.

The new app (keep in mind we are not live and still designing) so far feels more modular and separate.  The front stores state in services and will be a series of API calls to a series of endpoints.  The front team will be able to deploy and add features independent of the backend team.

So, by keeping them separate you enforce the boundary that will allow you to accomplish the independent deployability at least.  It is possible that it will be a better solution but should know sometime this time next year if that is completely the case.